# Inserting a template using a macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble inserting an excel template into a program. My intent is to press a button on the main file which will insert a sheet.  This program will be used by everyone in the office, so I'd like to be able to save the XLTM files in a common folder on our server, preferably with the main program.

The program runs fine, but I don't want everyone to have to save the XLTM files in their appdata>Microsoft>Roaming>Templates folder if they want to use it.

My code is as follows:

```
'name of the sheet template
    shName = "Wet Systems Template.xltm"

    'Insert sheet template

With ThisWorkbook
        Set sh = Sheets.Add(Type:=Application.TemplatesPath & shName, _
                            after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))

    End With
```

How can I modify this code to specify a particular location on our file server?

Thank you,

Comment: Changing `Application.TemplatesPath` to your path doesn't work?

Comment: It does work, but what if I want to save the templates somewhere on our server where everyone can access them?